# Why notion of fundamental group is defined only over a connected scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I went to different references on fundamental group on schemes. It is quite strange for me that the notion of fundamental group is only defined on connected scheme. Does anybody know why?

Comment: As Martin points out, it's not that we can't, it's just that it's just not a fruitful notion. This is very similar to the fact that a non-connected topological space has a fundamental group, but that it's values can be misleading (think of any space disjoint union a point, and think about the fundamental group based at that point).

Answer (score 3):

If we fix a point $x$ whose connected component is a proper subscheme, there is no way to capture the rest with the fiber functor at $x$. The correct notion would be the fundamental groupoid which should be well behaved for arbitrary schemes.